# MathTextParser: Fit output to figsize

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, figure

I am using `MathTextParser` to depict some equations in Qt. Therefore i get the required tex string out of a dict, parse it using the to_rgba method of the parser i created (handing over a general fontsize and dpi) and finally hand this to my `FigureCanvas` of the `QWidget` by `figimage`.
Have a look:

```
class MathWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
            QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
            ...
            self.canvas = MathCanvas() # The FigureCanvas to display the teximage
            ...
            self.parser = mathtext.MathTextParser("Bitmap")

    def render(self,metric):
            equation = self.equations[metric]
            rgb, d = self.parser.to_rgba(equation, color='black', fontsize=8, dpi=200)
            self.canvas.fig.figimage(rgb.astype(float)/255., 0, 0)
            self.canvas.draw()
```

My problem now is, that the equations to be parsed are of varying length whereas the  `FigureCanvas` has a fixed size (as it needs to have) so that it happens, that some equations result in an image, which exceeds the figure in its size so that some part of the equation is cut off/not visible, like in this example:
[Cut off equation](http://wwwpub.zih.tu-dresden.de/~s4901563/exceed.png)
What i wouldn't like to do is to somehow predefine a fontsize for every tex string depeding on its length, for the reason that even user defined equations (of unpredictable length) need to be parsed and displayed.
So is there by any chance a way to make the parser fit the e.g. fontsize, so that the output is a rasterized tex of a fixed size independently of the equation size/length?

Besides: In comparison to e.g. numpy/scipy the docs of matplotlib seem inscrutable to me for some reason, thus if somebody could comment on how `to_rgba` and `figimage` exactly work i'd be grateful, too.. e.g. concerning to_rgba: what means the following quote elucidating depth?:

> - depth is the offset of the baseline from the bottom of the image in pixels

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, what i did now (thanks to a colleague's advice) is smth like trial and error: i checked the arrays shape returned by the to_rgba method an depending on the shape i rerendered the string, using a bigger or smaller fontsize. though this demands the whole thingy in some cases to be rendered rendered twice or triple i doubt there is more satisfying solution...

Comment: Your proposed solution would work unless you had an equation that was way to big to fit, and came out as ants on the page when rendered in size 4 font or smaller.

I would maybe have an if statement in there for if the font size gets too small, and place the element in a QScrollArea or something similar.  Or you could also make it like a link, where if you clicked on it, it would show the full image.  A third solution you may consider, is having the tex of the equation accessible as mime data or on a right click.  Good luck.

Comment: hej, i dismissed the 'ScrollArea' idea already, whereas the link solution appeals to me if it can be implemented easily maybe even as mouseover, but is there a way to do it without /buffering/saving the images to hdd?

Comment: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/widgets-imageviewer.html Can you use the image scaling built into QT to simply re-size the image as needed?

Comment: @talkturkey Did you ever get this sorted out?

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution to display TeX code: Call `latex` to get a dvi file, then call `dvisvgm --no-fonts` to convert the dvi file to SVG, and then load and render the SVG file with QSvgRenderer:
[converting a latex code to mathml or svg code in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588261/converting-a-latex-code-to-mathml-or-svg-code-in-python/16893390#16893390)